# SQL, case expressions returns different results. Why?

Tags: sql

The two SQL statements retrun different results because I use different case expressions，What's the deep difference behind them?

```
select 
    course_name,
    case 
        when course_id in (select course_id from OpenCourses where month = 200706) 
            then 'o' 
            else 'x' 
    end as JUNE,
    case 
        when course_id in (select course_id from OpenCourses where month = 200707) 
            then 'o' 
            else 'x' 
    end as JULY,
    case 
        when course_id in (select course_id from OpenCourses where month = 200708) 
            then 'o' 
            else 'x' 
    end as AUG
from
    CourseMaster
```

[image]

```
select 
    course_name,
    case 
        when course_id = 200706 
            then 'o' 
            else 'x' 
    end as JUNE,
    case 
        when course_id = 200707 
            then 'o' 
            else 'x' 
    end as JULY,
    case 
        when course_id = 200708 
            then 'o' 
            else 'x' 
    end as AUG
from 
    CourseMaster
```

[image]

Create table scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE CourseMaster
(
    course_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    course_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CourseMaster VALUES(1, 'English');
INSERT INTO CourseMaster VALUES(2, 'Math');
INSERT INTO CourseMaster VALUES(3, 'Pyhsics');
INSERT INTO CourseMaster VALUES(4, 'Chemistry');

CREATE TABLE OpenCourses
(
    month     INTEGER,
    course_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(month, course_id)
);

INSERT INTO OpenCourses VALUES(200706, 1);
INSERT INTO OpenCourses VALUES(200706, 3);
INSERT INTO OpenCourses VALUES(200706, 4);
INSERT INTO OpenCourses VALUES(200707, 4);
INSERT INTO OpenCourses VALUES(200708, 2);
INSERT INTO OpenCourses VALUES(200708, 4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the contents of the `CourseMaster` table, the only values for `course_id` are 1, 2, 3, 4. Meanwhile in your second select with case, you check if `course_id` is 200706, 200707, 200708. That condition is not true on any of the records in `CourseMaster`, ergo all your case statements evaluate to the `else` branch, which is 'x'.

The two selects are **not** equivalent, logically. The first one checks if the course record you are looking at is listed in `OpenCourses` for the given month, the second one compares the `course_id` to the year-month value. The second select doesn't touch the `OpenCourses` table at all. The desired outcome of the SQL is not stated in the question, but the first select makes sense while the second one does not. The second SQL compares apples and oranges, in a sense - course_id's come from a different box of values (that's a metaphor, not a technical term) than your year-month values.

Comment: I updated the second SQL as following and realized the result is not “grouped” with each course name per line. Meanwhile the first SQL shows a "grouped" result.  this is why? Thanks.
`select course_name,
case when month  =200706 then 'o' else 'x' end as JUNE,
case when month  =200707 then 'o' else 'x' end as JULY,
case when month  =200708 then 'o' else 'x' end as AUG
from CourseMaster c left join OpenCourses o
on c.course_id=o.course_id`